# ImportError: cannot import name 'retry' from 'pip._vendor.retrying' (c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.retrying import retry  # type: ignore
ImportError: cannot import name 'retry' from 'pip._vendor.retrying' (c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py)
```

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'retry' from 'pip._vendor.retrying' (c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py)
```

focused down error here.

I was trying to install `ffmpeg` python module when I got this error above. Is there any way to fix it?

it seems that it was working fine before, just not now for some odd reason.

Comment: Does this also appear when you try to install other packages using pip?

Comment: Can you try `c:\python39\python.exe -c "from pip._vendor.retrying import retry"`? Does it work or produces the same error?

Comment: Welcome, are you using a [virtual environment or alternative IDE](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003226759-Pycharm-not-installing-new-packages-in-venv-if-inheriting-global-site-packages)?